# How to sign security tokens using SHA256 in WIF STS?

Tags: .net-4.5, wif, claims-based-identity, thinktecture-ident-model, thinktecture

I am using Thinktecture STS and would like to sign the issued tokens using SHA256 instead of SHA1?
I tried adding the algorithm to the application using:

```
CryptoConfig.AddAlgorithm(
         typeof(RSAPKCS1SHA256SignatureDescription),
         "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256");
```

But it starts giving error:

> Invalid algorithm specified

Knowing that the certificate I am using is compatible with SHA256.
Any idea?